# Why is this function returning None from the database?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following function:

```
def get_some_field(grouping_type_id):
    checkConnection() # establishes connection if none

    sql = "SELECT name FROM table_foo WHERE id=%d" % grouping_type_id
    results = conn.execute(sql)
    data = results.fetchone()
    return str(data['name']) if ((data) and ('name' in data)) else ''
```

If the database table is empty, I expect the function to return an empty string however, `None` is being returned instead.

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This also returns `'None'`:

```py
data = {'name': None}
result = str(data['name']) if ((data) and ('name' in data)) else ''
```

The problem is that `(data) and ('name' in data)` is truish, because `data` is not empty, and has `'name'` key set (although set to `None`, you do not check it).

Change this line:

```
return str(data['name']) if ((data) and ('name' in data)) else ''
```

into this line:

```
return str(data.get('name') or '') if data else ''
```

Comment: Won't that break if `data` is `None`?  I.e. an empty row per my bad answer below?

Comment: `str(data.get('name', ''))` will also return `'None'` with `{'name': None}`

Comment: @JoeFish, julio.alegria: You are both right, I added one part that fixes it.

Comment: the bug that @JoeFish commented wasn't fixed yet (`data` could be `None`)

Comment: Yikes, I see the problem, it was actually returning None as a string!. No wonder I was confused - I thought it was the `None` data type.

Comment: @julio.alegria: Ok, I previously fixed the issue you mentioned. I have edited my answer and added support for `data=None`.

Comment: `str(data and data.get('name') or '')` could also do the trick nicely :)

Comment: @julio.alegria: Agreed, but `str(data and data.get('name') or '')` is the old ([pre 2.5](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-308-conditional-expressions)) way of doing `str(data.get('name') if data else '')` :)

Answer (score -1):

I would assume because that's the documented sqlalchemy behavior.  [From the doc:](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_6/core/connections.html?highlight=fetchone#sqlalchemy.engine.base.ResultProxy.fetchone) (emphasis mine)

> fetchone()
>
> Fetch one row, just like DB-API cursor.fetchone().
>
> If a row is present, the cursor remains open after this is called.
>   Else the cursor is automatically closed **and None is returned**

.

Comment: -1, the question is not why `fetchone()` returns `None`, but why the function `get_some_field` returns `None`

Comment: Also, @julio.alegria thanks for the comment and not a silent -1.